# Count and list top 20 most repeated values of a certain field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please confirm the correct query to list the 20 most used hashtags and the count of numbers that they have been used in a MongoDB collection of tweets called "tweets"?

Each document in the collection represents a tweet.

Please find one of the documents (tweets) in JSON format [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hGy4I69R6jrr3G59w1_kQyaMx1kkVF0Jb_8bXuE8ttA/edit)

I tried the following query:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$entities.hashtags"},
    {"$group" : {_id:"$entities.hashtags", count:{$sum:1}}},
    { $sort   : { count : -1 } },
    { $limit  : 20 }
])
```

Unwind is used to separate documents that have multiple hashtags.

The output seems close:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "PrevenciónEsSalud",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            18
        ]
    },
    "count" : 118.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "DYK",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            4
        ]
    },
    "count" : 112.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "ActivadosPorLaSalud",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            20
        ]
    },
    "count" : 45.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            15, 
            23
        ]
    },
    "count" : 43.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "HelloMyNameIs",
        "indices" : [ 
            9, 
            23
        ]
    },
    "count" : 41.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "Quito",
        "indices" : [ 
            15, 
            21
        ]
    },
    "count" : 40.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "LoMásLeído",
        "indices" : [ 
            20, 
            31
        ]
    },
    "count" : 40.0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            18, 
            26
        ]
    },
    "count" : 39.0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            8
        ]
    },
    "count" : 38.0
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "PrevenciónGripe",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            16
        ]
    },
    "count" : 37.0
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            21, 
            29
        ]
    },
    "count" : 36.0
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            128, 
            136
        ]
    },
    "count" : 36.0
}

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            40, 
            48
        ]
    },
    "count" : 35.0
}

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "QuédateEnCasa",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            14
        ]
    },
    "count" : 35.0
}

/* 15 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "ICYMI",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            6
        ]
    },
    "count" : 35.0
}

/* 16 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "NosCuidamosTodos",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            17
        ]
    },
    "count" : 34.0
}

/* 17 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "JuntosEcuador",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            14
        ]
    },
    "count" : 34.0
}

/* 18 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            24, 
            32
        ]
    },
    "count" : 31.0
}

/* 19 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "EsteVirusLoParamosUnidos",
        "indices" : [ 
            0, 
            25
        ]
    },
    "count" : 28.0
}

/* 20 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "text" : "COVID19",
        "indices" : [ 
            23, 
            31
        ]
    },
    "count" : 28.0
}
```

However, the desired outcome is to have a column for the hastag and another one for the count, only for the top 20 most repeated hashtags.

I would appreciate your help in getting the top 20 most used hashtags in this collection.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by `the desired outcome is to have a column for the hastag` ?

Comment: I think you should group on `$entities.hashtags.text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group it like:

```js
$group: {
      _id: "$entities.hashtags.text",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
```